# CVS tags how do they exactly work?

Tags: cvs

I have a question concerned with tagging in CVS (I know there are better tools than cvs but this is what it is used in my company).

I have a project in CVS and over the past months people have applied lots of tags to it.
I had to make changes from a baseline which wasn't the latest tag.
So suppose you have the following tags in cvs:

Project_V1
Project_V2
Project_V3

The client asked for a couple of changes based on Project_V2.

My questions are:

1) If I commit my changes and then apply a new tag, will these changes be applied on top of Project_V3 or just on top of Project_V2?
2) If it is the way I think (i.e., they are applied on top of Project_V3) is there a way to avoid this and have something like:

Project_V1
Project_V2
Project_V2_B
Project_V3

so that the latest version of the software tagged as Project_V3 doesn't receive these changes?

Branching is currenlty not working for us, so it is not an option and that's why people have been tagging so far.

Thanks
M

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario asking is perfect case for branching.

Other wise, you might have to do some ugly code back-outs and re-checkins

```
Lets take one file and see how the history grows.
File A
  rev 1.1 
  rev 1.2 -> Label Project_V1
  rev 1.3
  rev 1.4
  rev 1.5 -> Label Project_V2
  rev 1.6
  rev 1.7 -> Label Project_V3
```

Now, since you want to make a change to File rev 1.5, You can branch from Label Project_V2 and create file changes. Now file revision will be 1.5.1.2.

```
File A
  rev 1.1 
  rev 1.2 -> Label Project_V1 
  rev 1.3
  rev 1.4
  rev 1.5 -> Label Project_V2 -> 1.5.1.2 -> Label Project_V2_B
  rev 1.6
  rev 1.7 -> Label Project_V3
```

Other solution (which I don't personally like) is to :

```
overwrite the latest files with files checked out using Label Project_V2 
make the necessary changes, apply label Project_V2_B.
Recheck-in the files from Label Project_V3.
```

```
File A
  rev 1.1 
  rev 1.2 -> Label Project_V1 
  rev 1.3
  rev 1.4
  rev 1.5 -> Label Project_V2 
  rev 1.6
  rev 1.7 -> Label Project_V3
  rev 1.8  (checkout from label Project_V2)
  rev 1.9 -> Label Project_V2_B
  rev 1.10 -> (check out from label Project_V3 and recheck-in) -> apply label again Project_V3
```

This makes a messy archive.